# Storing the session token in AWS Lambda function?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, microservices

I have a AWS Lambda function which need to talk to an external REST API. The external API needs a session token with every request.

I generate session token using client id and secret and then i use the session token with further requests to the external REST API.

I am currently storing the session token in mongodb (to persist data during lambda restarts) and retrieving it every time i need it. I think this is not the best way. what is the best / recommended way ?

Answer (score 3):

The approach you are using currently reasonable since its important to keep Lamda functions stateless while storing session information outside the function.

Without provisioning a MongoDB cluster, you can use Amazon DynamoDB to store the session data and retrieve for each request.

Note: If you are planning to do further performance improvements, you can consider using an in-memory database or DAX (If you use DynamoDB).

Comment: Thank you @Ashan for info around DynamoDB and DAX.